# Magento 2 Message Manager not working in custom module Front end Controller

Tags: frontend, controllers, magento2.2.2, exception, no-such-entity-exception

My controller without `try` `catch`:

```
class View extends Action
 {

  protected $resultPageFactory;
  protected $productRepository;
  protected $_messageManager;

  public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
  )
  {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
  }

  public function execute()
  {

    $resultPageFactory = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $productId = 10;
    $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $_product->getName();
    $resultPageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Custom 
    Controller'));
    return $resultPageFactory;
  }

}
```

And the exception in the front end display is:

```
1 exception(s):
 Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): 
 Requested product doesn't exist
 Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): 
 Requested product doesn't exist.....\
```

Now with `try` `catch` :

```
......
public function execute()
{

    $resultPageFactory = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    $productId = 10;
    try {
        $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
        print_r($_product->getName());
    }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        $this->_messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        print_r("Exception Occurred");
    }

    $resultPageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Custom 
    Controller'));
    return $resultPageFactory;
  }
  ......
```

The Front end display nicely but missing the exception message:
[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT:** Message with error on the page bellow e.g
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK!

Here is why the message wasn't displaying:

**cacheable="false"**

```
<referenceBlock name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Custom\View" 
     name="custom.view" template="Vendor_Module::custom/view.phtml" 
       cacheable="false"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

So the problem was that my custom phtml file needs `cacheable="false"` for it to work!

Now the message display nicely! :)

Thanks!

Comment: cacheable="false" is not right option to use, because it block entire page to get cached

Comment: yeah definitely. in mage2.3.5 is still an issue if one block is false will invalidate all other blocks too.